# Как вернуть удаленную ветку в Git после force push

Tags: android-studio, git, gitlab, git-push

Ситуация такая. По неопытности своей сделал force push проекта, после чего удалилась вся ветка с проектом и создалась новая с таким же именем, в которой теперь находится одна единственная версия. Благо, это не основная и не единственная ветка, но в ней последнее время велась разработка. Перед тем, как сделать push, скачивал копию проекта к себе на жесткий диск. Старую версию проекта со всей историей коммитов, опять же по глупости своей, c жесткого диска удалил. Можно ли отменить force push и вернуть удаленную ветку? Пользуюсь GitLab, force push делал через Android Studio. Пробовал команду reflog, пишет "not a git repository", вообще не пойму как тогда он сделал коммит и push. Затем создал git repository папке с проектом, пишет теперь, что ни одного коммита не было. Есть SHA последнего коммита до удаления ветки. В общем, помогите, если возможно еще хоть что-то сделать.

Answer (score 2):

Теоретически можно.

Нужно найти последний коммит, который был до `force push`. В теории до него можно достучаться из ленты событий.
После этого через тот же `force push`вернуться к этому коммиту.

Подробнейшую инструкцию см. [здесь](https://gist.github.com/Envek/13d9e406bb2af23f739197e3934ad4f0).

Но, будет ли прок (особенно если учесть, что Вы затёрли локальный репозиторий) не могу сказать.

Comment: у меня есть SHA предыдущих коммитов, но когда я пытаюсь сделать force push последнего, то выпадает ошибка error: src refspec ******** does not match any.